What properties of a relation are necessary in a ranking system?
This question is partially about the methodology / process of formulating a question, prior to seeking an answer.
Let’s say the minimum we know at the outset is that a group of people can rank each other on some scale of desirability, and we want to assign matches to people to achieve “a positive or satisfactory outcome”; like a stable matching problem.
The final formulation of the problem would be more specific, but we want to formally define the absolute minimum first, before we start adding in more.
We know we have a set of people, $S$. And we know that for each ordered pair $(p_1, p_2) \in S \times S$, we associate a “choice value”.
The ranking system could be integers on a scale of 1-5, or 1-10. Or it could be real numbers on a scale of 1-10, 0-1, 1-100, etc. Thus, we do not want to arbitrarily choose one of those options in our problem formulation. Instead, we want the elements of a choice values set to be totally ordered, first of all. So, $C$ is a set of choice values, and $\leq$ is a relation $\leq \subseteq C \times C$, with the properties of a total order - $\forall x, y \in C, x \leq y \vee y \leq x$.
The choice ranking relation is $R \subseteq S \times S \times C$. This relation is also total: $\forall x, y \in S, \exists r [(x, y, r) \in R]$.
The $R$ relation is not reflexive, since people will not be marrying/dating/befriending themselves. And it is also not transitive.
The next problem I think is that we cannot have an infinite ordered set, because it would mean that we can’t compare one person’s ranking to another’s. For example, maybe one person ranked their top choice a value of 1 million, and their lowest choice a 0, but another person used a ranking of 1–10. Maybe you could use “normalization”, where you scale their choice rankings relative to their highest and lowest choice value, but this is not conceptually sound, because we don’t know if their choices actually scale proportionally. So suggesting normalization is an example of getting ahead of yourself in the problem formulation. Instead, we want to think about exactly what abstract property is missing to make the ranking make sense conceptually.
What property should we add, regarding the ranking relation? I think the answer might just be that $C$ has a supremum and an infimum, but I wonder if there’s a deeper or more insightful way of arguing why that is.

If the choice values do have a supremum/infimum, does that actually solve the problem of two person's rankings not being directly comparable? If Alice rates someone a 5 while Bob rates them a 7, does that really tell you anything objective about that person? What if I then tell you that 5 is the highest that Alice has rated anyone, while 6 is the lowest Bob has rated anyone? What if Alice later rates someone a 10, demonstrating she was using a larger subset of the scale after all, she just didn't like anyone prior that much?

Basically I think your objection of not being able to compare one person's rankings to another has nothing to do with whether the choice set is infinite, it comes from not assuming that people are using the choice values to "mean" the same thing. But if you're not assuming that, what basis do you have to compare them at all? And if you are assuming that, then by assumption there's no need to normalise; if one person is using 1-1,000,000 then so is everyone else, so anyone who has only issued ratings of 1-10 just doesn't like anyone.
